# "Coal gas" or "coal gas"

Tags: capitalization

Do we write "coal gas" or "Coal gas"?

The latter is eventually a name of a specific gaseous mixture prepared by a specific way from coal.
I can imagine "coal gas" could be any gas related to coal, e.g. passing it, with composition very different to eventual "Coal gas", where some typical composition is expected.

(I have searched SE domain and general internet for coal Coal gas letter grammar, but have not found an answer. )

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal_gas

Comment: @Lambie Thanks, I am aware of the link, see my comments at [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/159711/what-is-the-difference-between-coal-gas-and-producer-gas). I guess I could imply it from usage "coal gas" there, but I have missed it at the time, or I may did not trust the correctness of it.

Comment: If you're referring to a specific thing with the same words that already refer to a broad category... then perhaps you need different words. If I want to invent a new kind of fishing boat, distinct from all the other fishing boats... then I should rely on more than a capitalized Fishing Boat to set it apart.

Comment: Related: having specific parameters does not make something a proper noun. We don't capitalize nitrogen gas, argon gas, etc., and it doesn't get any more specific than elements.

Comment: @AndyBonner Those gases are not good example. First we do not use AFAIK expression "element gas", but gaseous element or just element,  and second there is no class of many different "nitrogen gases" to name a specific one "Nitrogen gas".

Comment: Just thinking.....  What if some crazy boat company decided ( and was permitted to do so if it applies ) to name some their boat model "Fishing boat"? Would it justify the capital F for the name of product? What if Coal gas would be a name of a product of some early gas company as well?

Comment: @Poutnik If your question is "should they capitalize the 'B' in 'boat' as well," yes; unless there's a scenario that I'm overlooking, multi-word proper nouns capitalize both words. (Which means, if you did have reason to use "coal gas" as a proper noun, you should capitalize the "g" as well.) The fact stands, it's not a proper noun, and we don't use capitalization just for emphasis (at least, not in standard modern practice; earlier centuries and Winnie the Pooh do it all the time).

Comment: @Poutnik (Also, you're probably right that "gaseous nitrogen" is a more scientific way of talking about it, but it's definitely [less common than 'nitrogen gas'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nitrogen+gas%2Cgaseous+nitrogen&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnitrogen%20gas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgaseous%20nitrogen%3B%2Cc0).)

Comment: @AndyBonner  OK, thanks. I am fine with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the name of a product is derived from a particular place, the place name is a proper noun, so the first letter is capitalised, for example [Bordeaux wine](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bordeaux%20wine%2C%20bordeaux%20wine&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBordeaux%20wine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbordeaux%20wine%3B%2Cc0).

When the name of a product is derived from the main ingredient, then unless the main ingredient is a proper noun, the first letter of the ingredient name is not capitalised, for example [barley wine](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Barley%20wine%2Cbarley%20wine&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBarley%20wine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbarley%20wine%3B%2Cc0).

Coal is not a proper noun, so the first letter is not capitalised in "coal gas".

Note that Cheddar is a place but cheddar cheese is made by the process of cheddaring, regardless of where it is made: the name is derived from the process, not the place, so the name should not be capitalised.

Comment: I'm not so sure about Cheddar cheese, living as I do 15 miles from the place, and neither is [this person](http://cheddarbound.blogspot.com/2007/10/big-cheddar-or-small-cheddar.html)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey My brother in law lives 4km from Cheddar, and his uncle is a cheese maker, so my information isn't quite from the horse's mouth, but it's close. A French intern at my office once asked an English colleague what was her favourite English cheese. She replied "Canadian cheddar". Not everybody who expresses an opinion about cheese knows what they are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The gas used until about 50 years ago in my country (the UK) for heating and cooking, made from coal, was called in writing 'coal gas' (both words all lower case). Use of a capital C would be incorrect.

> By-products from the production process included coal tars and
> ammonia, which were important chemical feedstock for the dye and
> chemical industry with a wide range of artificial dyes being made from
> **coal gas** and coal tar.

The production of coal gas has ceased in the UK, apart from gas used internally in coke production plants.